# Find duplicate String inside a text with middle near each other

Tags: grep, scripting, bioinformatics

I need to find a string of 13 character length in a text file that has a duplicate close to it.
It referencing to the mutation 13 of the genomes.

For example:

ACGAATTGCAGCCACAGTACGAATCGCAGCC.

It starts with ACGAATTGCAGCC and ends with it, but in between are random chars of unknown length.

What I've come up so far is:

```
grep -Eo '((.){13}).{1,100}\1'
```

### I have to find it in this

> GTACCATAACTAACAACCTGAAAAGTCACAAAAACATATACAATAAAAGAACTAGATTTCGCATAGGATATATATTAATAAAGTGAACAAAAAAAAAATAACAACAACAACAACGAATGAAGAAAGGAAAAGGAATGATAAAAAAACGAGTAATAATTGAAAACAATTATAAAGTAAGAAAACCGCAACGGCCCAAGTAAGCAAAGCAAGGATAGGAAATTGATCGACACAACTCCATAAAATTTACAACTAGTACTCAGAAAAAATAACTAAGCTATATCCATATCTACTCTAAAAAAGAAAAGGAATAACGGAACACCCACAAAGAAACTCAATTAGCAAAAACCACAGATAATACAAACCAGAGAAGACCACATAAAAAAATGAACGAGTTACCCTTCAAATTAAAATAAATCTACCAGTAAGCATAAAAACAACAAAGTTACAAAACCAAAGACCAAAAGTAGAAATCAGAACAAGGGACATAAACGTTCACCAAATGAATGAAACAACACAATTTAGAAACAAAAAAGAGGAATAAAAAGCCAGAACAGGAGTACGAACATAATTAATTATGAAAGTGACCTACAAATAAGAAGGAAACACAAACAGAAAACAACTAACCACAAAAAAGACATAATAGTAAACAAAAAAAAAAAACTTACTCATACGAGGACTAATAAAAGATTCAAAACAATACAATTGACGAAAACTCAACGAGGAAAGCTAGAAAACCACCAGAGAAACTCAAAACACAAATAGAGATAAAAAAAAAAACCATAAAGAAAAATTCTTACATCGTCACAGCCAAGGAAAAAAAGAAATCGTTAAAATGGAACGCAGTCGAACACAAAAAGACAACACAGAACAAAAAAGGCAAACAGCGTAGAAACAAATACACTCGCGTAGCAAAGGGGCGGCGTCACGCTTGAAACATAAAAATAACCACTGTATATCACGACAATCAACAAAGTCTACATCAAGAAAATCAAAAAAATAC

Answer (score 2):

You were quite close, the problem was the 100, too narrow!  You may want to consider using Perl PCRE as opposed to Posix Extended. The performance difference is quite noticeable.

```
grep -Po '((.){13}).{1,1000}?\1' genom
AACAAAAAAAAAATAACAACAACAACAACGAATGAAGAAAGGAAAAGGAATGATAAAAAAACGAGTAATAATTGAAAACAATTATAAAGTAAGAAAACCGCAACGGCCCAAGTAAGCAAAGCAAGGATAGGAAATTGATCGACACAACTCCATAAAATTTACAACTAGTACTCAGAAAAAATAACTAAGCTATATCCATATCTACTCTAAAAAAGAAAAGGAATAACGGAACACCCACAAAGAAACTCAATTAGCAAAAACCACAGATAATACAAACCAGAGAAGACCACATAAAAAAATGAACGAGTTACCCTTCAAATTAAAATAAATCTACCAGTAAGCATAAAAACAACAAAGTTACAAAACCAAAGACCAAAAGTAGAAATCAGAACAAGGGACATAAACGTTCACCAAATGAATGAAACAACACAATTTAGAAACAAAAAAGAGGAATAAAAAGCCAGAACAGGAGTACGAACATAATTAATTATGAAAGTGACCTACAAATAAGAAGGAAACACAAACAGAAAACAACTAACCACAAAAAAGACATAATAGTAAACAAAAAAAAAA
```

Timing comparison on my machine:

```
Posix: (-E)  0m4.816s
Perl:  (-P)  0m0.011s
```

Comment: You may want to make the repetition non greedy `.{1,1000}?`, even if this may not matter in this exact case, you only want to include up to the nearest repetition. That horrible slowness with `-E` looks like a bug (`LC_ALL=C` will cut it to 1/3, but still orders of magnitude slower than `-P`).

Comment: Good suggestion! Thanks - will incorporate :)

Comment: P.S.: @mosvy - nice catch w/ the LC_ALL ... that brings the runtime down to `0m0.714s` ... almost sevenfold faster. Still a good tick slower than `-P`. :)

Comment: Note that POSIX EREs don't have back references. (POSIX BREs do). The OP is probably using an implementation that offers it as an extension.